# switch rows between 2 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, swap

I have 2 dataframes looking like this :

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
       'col2': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
       'col3': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
       'cond': [5000, 6000, 6001, 5000, 6002, 6003, 5000, 6004, 6005, 5001]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
       'col2': [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
       'col3': [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
       'cond': [6000, 5000, 5001, 6000, 5002, 5003, 6000, 5004, 5005, 6001]})
```

I need to swap rows between the two dataframes based on the condition column, the values which are 5000±100 should be in one dataframe and the values 6000±100 in another:

```
df_expected1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 9, 8, 4, 6, 5, 7, 3, 2, 10],
                'col2': [1, 9, 8, 4, 6, 5, 7, 3, 2, 10],
                'col2': [1, 9, 8, 4, 6, 5, 7, 3, 2, 10],
                'cond': [5000, 5000, 5001, 5000, 5002, 5003, 5000, 5004, 5005, 5001]})

df_expected2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [10, 2, 3, 7, 5, 6, 4, 8, 9, 1],
                'col2': [10, 2, 3, 7, 5, 6, 4, 8, 9, 1],
                'col2': [10, 2, 3, 7, 5, 6, 4, 8, 9, 1],
                'cond': [6000, 6000, 6001, 6000, 6002, 6003, 6000, 6004, 6005, 6001]})
```

Comment: do you always have one value around 5k and one around 6k? If, not can you provide examples of how you want to handle it?

Comment: your dataframes are dictionaries, is this on purpose?

Comment: @mozway yes they are always centered around the same value.  if abs(df1["cond"].loc[i] - df2["cond"].loc[i] ) >  + 200:
       df1.loc[i], df2.loc[i] = df2.loc[i], df1.loc[i] . I know this code is wrong but this is the idea I had .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First concatenate the two dataframes and then split them based on column `cond`:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_index()

df_expected1 = df[df.cond < 5500]
df_expected2 = df[df.cond > 5500]
```

I assumed here that `df1` and `df2` are dataframes. Value `5500` is arbitrarily chosen, maybe you need to change this.

If the output needs to be a dictionary, you can use `.to_dict()`.

Comment: But this way I would loose the right order. Actually the 2 dataframes are for 2 diffrent events but they got mixed up and I need to seperate the data but keep the right order

Comment: If you want the order defined by index number: use `.sort_index()`